# What does the loc abbreviation mean in GitHub?

Tags: github

For any file (e.g., [this one](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/utils/actionTypes.ts)) GitHub displays info above the viewer, like `17 lines (14 loc)`.

What does the `14 loc` part mean?

Answer (score 0):

LOC stands for Lines of Code or Lines of Content - a count of non-empty lines.